# How do you feed as a vampire when everyone is attacking you on Skyrim Elder Scrolls Xbox 360 version?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Yes, I know that you have to use Seduction or whatever, but when ever I approach someone I always get attacked. So how am I supposed to feed to go back to level one????

Comment: Did you try sneaking up on them?

Answer (score 1):

Sneaking is the obvious solution, small towns like Rorikstead are the easiest for this due to the lack of guards.  I've found that it's almost impossible to charm and feed on anyone outside even at night since someone always walks in on it, so just sneak into a house and feed on someone there.

If sneaking isn't your thing, go to a bandit camp/cave, kill all the bandits but one and then charm that bandit.  Try to feed on a low level bandit to reduce the chances of them making the save against the charm.